# Swift data conversion error: Cannot convert the expression's type '$T5' to type 'NSDictionary'

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting the following error message at the line i give a comment:

> "Cannot convert the expression's type '$T5' to type 'NSDictionary'"

Here is the code

```
func auctionLatestDefault(completion : (error: NSError?,result : AnyObject?) -> Void){
    Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://localhost:8080/xxx/xxx/xx/xxx/").response {
        (_, _, data, error) in

        var err : NSError?

        if error == nil{

            var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary //Error

            var results : NSArray = jsonResult["body"] as NSArray
        }

        else{
            println("Nothing!")
        }
    }

}
```

This is my json,i have change Alamofire response to "responseJSON"

```
    {
  "body" : [
    {
      "id" : "bbXqpjhpGRDUlBd",
      "priv" : "",
      "average" : "3606000",
      "equip" : "",
      "chassis" : "EXD52D6"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you fill me in with the JSON object?

Comment: you mean you want the output of "data"?

Comment: Yep, the pure JSON string.

Comment: I have updated the code.All i want is 15 results of "image0,vendorName & modelName" inside body{} to show at tableview

Answer (score 0):

Educated guess: The type of the `data` instance is actually `NSData?` and not `NSData`

Try to replace

```
if error == nil{
    var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary //Error
    var results : NSArray = jsonResult["body"] as NSArray
}
else{
    println("Nothing!")
}
```

with

```
if let data = data {
    var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary //Error
    var results : NSArray = jsonResult["body"] as NSArray
}
else {
    println("couldn't get data \(error)")
}
```